# plot generated by matplotlib/hist2d looks different on the screen and pdf file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Matplotlib 2.2.2 to generate a `hist2d` plot. It looks fine on the screen, but when I save it into a pdf file, the boxes have gray edges around them. Why? I did not encounter this problem using Matplotlib 1.5.3, only after I upgraded to 2.2.2.

This what I used to make the plot:

```
ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=(900, 1500), cmap=plt.cm.Reds, norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
```

On the **left**, you can see the plot as it appears in a PDF with the grey boxes.
The plot on the **right** is how it appears on the screen

[image: plot shows on the screen]
[image: plot shows on the screen]

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem if you export to other formats (i.e. is it an export error)? Try postscipt (.ps) or SVG, and also a rasterised format such PNG. If you change the DPI, does the problem persist (i.e. is the problem maybe due to anti-aliasing)?

Comment: @Paul, Thanks. JPEG and SVG are fine, but PS format makes the background black even though it looks as it should be (white) on the screen. It is hard to judge whether this grey boxes exist or not. Nothing changes for the PDF format by tweaking DPI or anti-aliasing settings.  PDF or PS are still my preferred format.

Comment: It more and more sounds like a matplotlib bug. You should raise an issue on the matplotlib github. In my experience, the maintainers are pretty quick to respond if you write a halfway decent bug report (which should be straightforward in your case). In the meantime, you should be able to easily convert the svg files to pdfs (hopefully without the rendering issues).

Comment: This seems to be still unresolved, have the exact same issue when saving .pdf